# I want to set input value

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <input id="_onSpeech" onBlur="simpleFcs();"> <br>
            <button id="_onSpeechBtn" onClick="resetValue();">Gönder</button>
<script>
function resetValue(){
    document.getElementById("_onSpeech").innerHTML="";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to set inputs value to NULL or "" (empty) when i click the "_onspeechBtn"
I also tried .value option too but its still not working.

Comment: `document.getElementById("_onSpeech").value =""` Your id don't even match.

Comment: I said that, i tried this too but not working.

Comment: Try matching ids instead of totally different ones that don't exist

Comment: `_onSpeech` is different from `speech1`.

Comment: Problem not about that. I editted it.

Comment: `input` elements cannot have `innerHTML`. They do have a `value` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function resetValue(){
    document.getElementById("_onSpeech").value="";
}
```

```html
<input id="_onSpeech" >
<br>
<button id="_onSpeechBtn" onClick="resetValue();">Gönder</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your id seems to be wrong.

```
document.getElementById("_onSpeech").value = "";
```